# upgrade more than 50 installations to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

as web designers we had a good year 2011 with more than 50 (different) cms & other php 5.2 driven applications. Some had customizations to core as well.
How does someone upgrade such amount of apps to php 5.3?

Do developers of php ever thought about that?
Much (popular) functions are just depreciated causing a lot of work to people like us.

I really don't know how to best proceed

Comment: Don't customize frameworks/CMSs other than via approved means (plugins and what not) in the first place. You'll have to upgrade PHP, and then hand-correct the issues. And you may not be able to upgrade the frameworks/CMSs without great effort.

Comment: @DampeS8N That's sort of a blanket statement there. I've been forced to modify core before because the framework I used didn't support functionality that I needed. A plugin wouldn't have changed that.

Comment: @jprofitt Was it Open Source? Could you not contribute your improvements to the community at large? If your chosen framework doesn't support your needs, you chose wrong.

Comment: @DampeS8N:  Where's the guarantee that any framework chosen will meet all of one's needs, now and after you've chosen it?   If you're clairvoyant, and there are many frameworks addressing different aspects, then you can pick the right one in advance.  Us mere mortals suffer from the reality of not being able to do this right.

Comment: @IraBaxter Which is why you need to plan out what you are going to do, read the documentation of lots of frameworks, and pick one that does the things you need or can be extended with plugins you create to do what you need.

Comment: @DampeS8N: Nobody disagrees that you try to plan things out carefully.  The disagreement is your implied assertion that you know what you need in the future accurately, that you won't make any mistakes in your assessment, the world won't change around you, or the framework builders won't hand you a surprise.

Comment: No Framework, except the one you do yourself, can satisfy 100% of your needs. There are time where you need to do modifications.

Comment: However, i know that touching core files is wrong. There are times where you need to do modifications to achieve specific functionality. Different clients have different custom needs. Even if you have to touch your own framework, it does not matter, there is much headache caused..  But: it is not a secret to developers of such popular scripting language, and they know what stupid effort it is to mass-update (now outdated) applications.

Comment: @Grashopper No framework, *including* the one you write yourself, can satisfy 100% of your needs *for very long*, as in any non-trivial project requirements will change. I've been naive enough to think I covered all my bases in custom work, and I did for about 2 weeks.

Comment: Planning ahead, setting up a testing infrastructure beforehand and test environments for new stuff have worked out just fine for us, enabling us to make a good use of new technology as it comes along. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The short answer

#### It depends.

The strategy for migration would be influenced by the quality and content of the source itself, as well as the architecture and workflow. There is no "silver bullet" to *make it work*.

## Longer answer

#### How it should be done

You automatically upgrade all the [staging sites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_site), run all the [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and if they all pass - run the [acceptance tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing). Fix the issues that arise till you can pass all the tests. Then let your QA people make sure that everything is really 100% OK. This whole process would mostly run by your [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) system/framework.

When all works on the staging environment, you take down each site for maintenance, deploy the updated code to the production environment, upgrade the server's software, and bring the sites back up.

#### How you will (most likely) HAVE to do it

Since none of your software has any unit/acceptance tests, no up-to-date specification, or even notion of continuous integration system, you will have to do it the hard way:

```
'step 1' take a survey of different servers setups on which your projects 
         are deployed (if you have all project on single box with 
         virtual-hosts, you can skip this bit )
'step 2' find somewhere a computer, which can temporary act as local server
<foreach setup>

    'step 3' install/configure this temporary server to be exactly like 
             the "setup"
    <foreach project on that setup>

        'step 4' BACKUP ALL THE STUFF
        'step 5' copy the latest source and DB from the production server
        'step 6' upgrade the software
        'step 7' see what has *blown* up and fix what you can find    
        'step 8' pass to the QA team 
        'step 9' store the source

    </endforeach project>
    'step 10' take the server with this configuration down for maintenance
    'step 11' upgrade software on the server
    'step 12' deploy all the projects from this server 
    'step 13' prayer (optional)

<endforeach setup>
```

This is kinda the "brief" version. Basically you will have to go server-by-server, clone it locally, then upgrade, patch projects. Then upgrade each server and put the patched version on. And hope.

#### Should you upgrade ?

> <sub>**Clients will not pay for this.**</sub>

Since you have ~50 different projects, you would have to investigate if it's even worth the time and money. After such analysis you might discover that it would make more sense for a business to mark most of the projects as *"legacy"* and just upgrade server(s) to latest 5.2.x. Then leave it alone.

Of course even if you decide to not upgrade most of the projects, there will be some that will require it. Particularly project with ongoing contracts, which generate a steady stream of income for the company.

I would recommend to start upgrading those cash-cow projects, because you will have to anyway. And then from this experience you can calculate the costs for the rest of your "portfolio".

#### What about next time ?

PHP 5.4 is out (at the time of last edit, 5.5 is already coming). Most companies by the end of this year will be faced with a question: *"Is it time to start using 5.4 ?"*. Some sooner, some a bit later. The frameworks and CMSs, that you use, too have a tendency to get updates.

**Bottom line:** your company as whole should start to investigate ways to streamline this process.

And what about when you upgrade to PHP 5.5 and `mysql_*` functions start showing `E_DEPRECATE` warnings? See the **red box** in [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) documentation. This is not a one-time thing.

It might be wise to invest in implementing better deployment strategy (something that involves unit-tests and continuous integration).

---

<sub>`<rant>`</sub>

> <sub>Do developers of php ever think about that? Many (popular) functions are just depreciated causing a lot of work to people like us.</sub>

<sub>The functions and functionality, that has been deprecated, has been marked as such in documentation for ages. For example, the notice, that `ereg()` and passing object by reference should not be used, has been there since I began learning PHP. The deprecation warnings would affect mostly PHP4 codebase (in which case, your question is a bit disingenuous).</sub>

<sub>I do not see how enforcing practices, which have been accepted in the community for years, is "causing a lot of work".</sub>

<sub>`</rant>`</sub>

Answer (score 3):

First, by having your programmes stored in packages (RPM, DEB, etc) installed via a package management system (yum, apt-get, etc) with the dependancy information correctly set.

Then by having a proper release chain with an integration step that tests if code breaks when you upgrade dependancies. A CI server such as Jenkins can run your automated tests and build packages for you.

If there are problems, they show up quickly and you can get to work on fixing them. Use your usual internal processes for prioritisation and fixing of bugs (noting that it is worth focusing on all bugs introduced by a dependancy upgrade in a given package as a batch, and not splitting effort by working on a dozen programs in parallel).

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you should follow suggested upgrade practices; other answers are providing them.

There are process and procedural steps to take; I have no specific suggestions there, and in fact [tereško](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/teresko)'s answer is pretty good IMHO

But where the code base itself has to be changed, you may have a choice:

- You can do it all by hand (that seems to be the implicit assumption).  This isn't surprising advice.
- You might be able to automate the application of the changes.

The purely manual approach requires you to discover all the types of incompatibilities (language changes, framework changes, infrastructure replacement, ...), figuring out how to fix them generally, and then applying each fix type where appropriate.  That last part is really expensive because it requires you to examine every line of code, and fix it if it is wrong.

Automated change can't help with the discovery of issues, or the general working out of solutions.  But once you figure out how to solve a problem, it could probably help with applying that solution in all the places necessary.

What's needed for each problem is a kind of "if you see this in the code, change it to that".  That informal idea can be packaged as a *program transformation*, formal rules for modifying code.

My company offers a tool, the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html), which is a program transformation engine.  It can analyze and transform many kinds of computer source code using language-specific front ends; it has a [PHP front end (parser/prettyprinter)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/PHPFrontEnd.html) suitable for this task.  DMS was designed for this kind of task, which is why part of its name is "software reengineering toolkit".  We've used it for [much nastier reengineering tasks](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Services/NorthropGrummanB2.html).

So the idea is to package up the needed changes as program transformations, and use a tool like DMS to apply them.    It will be effort to write the rules that fix the issues in your code, but once done DMS can apply those rules reliably.  So you invest in the first few systems (to get the rules tuned and validated) to make updating the last 48 odd efficient.

This isn't a panacea; you can't always easily write a transformation for what you want.  But when you have a lot of changes to make, and you want to make them all over your code, doing as many as you can *reliably* with a tool is far better than doing everything by hand.

Comment: Common people.. that is exactly the problem. Programmers think like programmers and really don't care if their developed code (and changes) causes serious problems and workload to others. You all proposing solutions which a) need additional knowledge and practice b) complex approach to a simple problem: build your code so others can use, work, update with ease

Comment: @Grashopper Word, Dude ! 100% Agreement !

Comment: @Grashopper: Forgive my denseness... "You all proposing solutions solutions.... " you are referring to my answer?  "... which need additional knowledge and practice ... "  well, yes; it is clear that to update your 50 systems you need knowledge about what is wrong with them; I'm just suggesting casting that knowledge in a form that helps you apply it repeatedly, "... complex approach to simple problem"  Hmm. DMS is complex, true. The issue is how complex or expensive is *your* problem in comparison? Steamshovels are more complex than spoons, but if you want a big hole spoons are a bad choice.

Comment: @Grashopper: "... build your code so others can use, work, update with ease..." Are you complaining about the PHP engine, or your code base?

Comment: @Grashopper There aren't too many deprecated functions in PHP. Converting them programatically with knowledge and practice is easy, by creating your own parser in c, c++, java, .net or even in PHP, and if you don't want to create it, you can always use a third party tool since you had a good 2011 year. And in the worst escenario you can even edit  PHP 5.4 source to keep all deprecated functions... I don't really see any trouble.

Comment: @renamr: "... is easy, by creating your own parser ..."  You obviously haven't done this, or what you and I call parsers are radically different animals.  I have personally built such a parser for PHP4 and PHP5, suitable for reengineering tasks. The amount of detail is surprising, and the language is poorly documented to boot. And in general you need a lot more than just a parser, for instance, how are you going to modify the code after you parse it?.  See my essay on LifeAfterParsing http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this list: http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php is all you have to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to proceed would be to follow the [PHP 5.3 Migration Guide](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php)  (and then to [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php)).

Comment: of course. OP is objecting to the level of effort it takes to do this for a large number of applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an alternative Webserver like cherokee you can use parallel Installations of PHP. If you are unable to do so because of installation restrictions in your os you can always use a chrooted environment and change the ports of your php interpreter.

If I have to update a php version I add a second domain to the page e. g. updated.domain.com that uses the new php version. Normal users will see no difference. But unfortunately this will only work, if you work with relative paths and without hard coded domains in your files.

Comment: Why can't I use parallel installations of PHP with the non-alternative  webserver? Don't you construct differences here a little? However, the idea is not bad to allow differentiated updates of the PHP version and switching PHP versions on a per application level and not globally.

Comment: I didn't work with a apache for about 5 years. Maybe it works, maybe not - don't know. But I have done this a few times with cherokee and nginx.